# Emacs Lisp macro stepper

Tags: emacs, macros, elisp

Is there an Elisp analogue for the SLIME macrostepper? Specifically, I'm looking for something that expands code at point into the next expansion step (or just the final expansion) in a new buffer.

The naive

```
(defun macroexpand-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((b (get-buffer-create "*el-macroexpansion*"))
        (expansion (format "%s" (macroexpand (thing-at-point 'sexp)))))
    (with-current-buffer b
      (insert expansion)
      (display-buffer b))))
```

doesn't do what I'm expecting here.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does this do exactly? Can't really find anything on macro-stepper

Comment: @Dualinity - It takes the elisp macro call at point and shows you the code it expands out to in a temp buffer. If that still doesn't make sense, you may need to read up on [macros in Lisp](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/Lisp-Notes/Macros.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you need this:

```
(defun macroexpand-sexp-at-point ()
  (macroexpand (sexp-at-point)))
```

The whole function can be expressed more succintly thus

```
(defun macroexpand-point (sexp)
  (interactive (list (sexp-at-point)))
  (with-output-to-temp-buffer "*el-macroexpansion*"
    (pp (macroexpand sexp)))
  (with-current-buffer "*el-macroexpansion*" (emacs-lisp-mode)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You may find that [imacroexpand.el](http://www.mail-archive.com/gnu-emacs-sources@gnu.org/msg00603/imacroexpand.el) does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

One might find the [macrostep package](https://github.com/joddie/macrostep) useful.

Quick howto on macrostep:

After you install the package, and without further customization, you can do this:

Move cursor before the expression you want to expand, then do `M-x macrostep-expand e e e e e` to expand it step by step. Short help message gets displayed in the echo area on how to quit and how to unexpand.

One can test this out on the `->>` macro examples from [dash.el page](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el), which are not too simple and not too complicated.